# Why is UtteranceProgressListener not an interface?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm playing around with Android's TTS features and the TextToSpeech class has this method to set a listener which gets notified once the TextToSpeech has finished playing:

```
public int setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener listener)
```

But the `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` is defined as `public abstract class`. As my `MainActivity` already extends Activity, it can't extend `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` as well. I could use the older method with a `OnUtteranceCompletedListener`, but this is deprecated:

```
public int setOnUtteranceCompletedListener (TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener listener)`
```

Why is `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` not defined as `public static interface`? I'm thinking to write my own `UtteranceProgressListenerImpl`, which will then just call the `MainActivity`s `onDone` method. Is this the proper way or is there a better/cleaner alternative?

```
private class UtteranceProgressListenerImpl extends UtteranceProgressListener {

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    UtteranceProgressListenerImpl(MainActivity mA) {
        mainActivity = mA;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        mainActivity.onDone(utteranceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) { /* empty */ }

    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) { /* empty */ }


}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know I think it should be an interface as well. I use this code to get around it. It is available [here](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/voiceaction/VoiceActionExecutor.java) as well.

Also, vote for [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23808) I submitted a while ago.

```
public void setTts(TextToSpeech tts)
    {
        this.tts = tts;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15)
        {
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId)
                {
                    onDoneSpeaking(utteranceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId)
                {
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "set utternace completed listener");
            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId)
                {
                    onDoneSpeaking(utteranceId);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: An alternative solution to the anonymous inner class is to create a completely separate (non-anonymous) inner class that extends UtteranceProgressListener. This was the approach I adopted when I revised an application that used text to speech. However I have since received a couple of NoClassDefFoundError exceptions in the developer console and have come to the conclusion that this approach is unsound (no pun intended). It appears that occasionally the classloader is unable to load the class either in time or at all (it's hard to tell which). So don't adopt that route.