# Why do I get this error while implementing UtteranceProgressListener?

Tags: interface, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

[image]

I have to do something when the `Utterance` is completed so I have implemented `UtteranceProgressListener` but it shows

> Interface expected here

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

The [UtteranceProgressListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) is not an interface, unlike the deprecated [OnUtteranceCompletedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html). Someone asked [a question as to why here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11703653/1256219).

Instead, I would recommend implementing it from an inner class:

```
private final UtteranceProgressListener myProgressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStart(final String utteranceId) {
    }


    // Continue to override the other methods you want here
};
```

Then use by setting:

```
    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(myProgressListener);
```

Or alternatively:

```
   tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
   // Overrride here
   });
```